# Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: php, mysql, magento

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '202-564' for key
>   'UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_PRODUCT_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID', query
>   was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_super_attribute` (`product_id`,
>   `attribute_id`) VALUES (?, ?)

Comment: Bem vindo ao sopt. Acredito que sua intenção foi compartilhar uma solução de um problema que teve mas você precisa elaborar a pergunta, e não simplesmente postar um código de erro. Leia [ask] para saber como elaborar uma boa pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

a solução foi

```
delete ci FROM catalog_product_super_attribute as ci 
left join  catalog_product_entity as ce ON ci.product_id = ce.entity_id;
```